# How to implement counting sort for integers in Clojure?

Tags: sorting, clojure, counting-sort

Say I have an array of integers `xs` taking values from `0` to `max`, and I need to sort it in O(n) time, so I can't just do `(sort xs)`.

Is there a way to do it with the `frequencies` function?

In another language I would then do a `for` to iterate over integers from `0` to `max`, and for each value `x` in that range, look up `(frequencies x)` and then do `repeat (frequencies x) x` or something.

Crucially I need to do this IN ORDER from smallest to highest, which is what makes the whole thing a sort. So I DON'T want to just `map` each number in `xs`.

Any ideas for a clojure-ish idiomatic solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't be too quick to dismiss `(sort xs)`.  It's probably faster than any code you could write.  If you really need a custom solution, look at the [data.int-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.int-map) library for dealing with integer keys.

Comment: You cannot do better than `(sort xs)`.  When you add up the cost for `(frequencies xs)` and add in the many `(repeat frequencies x) x)` stuff it will cost more than `(sort xs)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a vector isn't quite O(1) but you can use that to create the counts for each element:

```
(defn counting-sort [s]
  (if (empty? s)
    s
    (let [counts (reduce (fn [v e]
                           (update v e inc))
                         (vec (repeat (inc (apply max s)) 0))
                         s)]
      (apply concat (map-indexed #(repeat %2 %1) counts)))))
```

Comment: Thanks - will have to grok this. How could this be made to work for `bigint`s?

Comment: @Rucksack - It already works if the elements are `bigint`s but if you actually need the range of `bigint` the size of the frequencies vectors will be much too large for counting sort.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just do what you said with clojure:

```
(let [xs [1 2 1 4 1 5 1 8 7 7 7]
      fs (frequencies xs)
      max 10]
  (into [] 
    cat
    (for [i (range max) :when (contains? fs i)]
      (repeat (get fs i) i))))
```

Comment: Ah cool, that's what I was initially looking for - couldn't quite put it all together myself, thanks. Is this still (nearly) linear time, like @Lee's answer?